# Can't read received packet when the data section starts with 2

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

so... context: I'm doing a layer 2 protocol for flexible forwarding in vehicular environment (for now my testbed is in virtual machines), this should take in consideration a different number of interfaces (for multihoming) and multihop.

So what I have:
A way of broadcasting hop-by-hop the service provider.

What I'm triyng to do:
A way to register a session all the way from the client to the provider (And here is the problem)

Problem: I have two types of packets
1st is listened correctly and data payload starts with a 1
2nd for some reason is not detected but I can see the packet is sent and correct with tcpdump

Since I have to register in the application the interface where the connection is made I used select() which seems to be part of the problem since I only guessed how it was used and I'm kind of in the dark about this.

UPDATED v3:

Okay so as soon as I removed most of the stuff about only sending on a specific interface all the stuff worked perfectly (I still need to clean this code... it's kind of messy). Here is code if someone is interested:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>

#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define ETH_P_CUSTOM    0x0801  /* EtherType of Current Used Protocol*/
#define BUF_SIZE        1024

typedef enum {
    false, true
} Bool; /* Boolean Definition*/

typedef struct Stat {
    uint8_t maxSocket; /*Number of sockets to use in receive*/
    uint8_t nInterfaces; /*Number of interfaces owned by this machine*/
    uint8_t nSession; /*Number of Sessions Known in the linked list*/

    uint8_t upMac[ETH_ALEN]; /*MAC of this host upstream parent*/
    uint8_t nHops; /*Hops to Provider*/
    char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE + 1]; /*Interface to Provider*/
} Stat;

typedef struct Node {
    uint64_t session; /*Client Session*/
    uint8_t nextHop[ETH_ALEN]; /*Next-Hop to Client*/
    char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE + 1]; /*Outgoing Interface that connects to Next-Hop*/
    struct Node * next; /*Next Session*/
} Node;

typedef struct ifNode {
    uint8_t ifIndex; /*Interface index*/
    uint8_t sock; /*Index in array of sockets*/
    uint8_t mac[ETH_ALEN]; /*Interface MAC*/
    char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE + 1]; /*Interface Name*/

    struct ifNode * next; /*Next Session*/
} ifNode;

Stat * op; /* Variable which tracks status of certain structures/variables*/
Node * first = NULL, *last = NULL; /* Edges of linked list */
ifNode * iffirst = NULL, *iflast = NULL; /* Edges of interface linked list */
int cargc;
char **cargv;

int receiveP();
int broadServ();
int announceSelf();

Node* create(uint64_t sess, uint8_t n[ETH_ALEN], char interface[IF_NAMESIZE]);
void insert_node(Node * p);
Node* search(uint64_t session);
void update(uint64_t session, Node * p);

ifNode* createif(uint8_t idx, uint8_t sock, uint8_t ifmac[ETH_ALEN],
        char interface[IF_NAMESIZE]);
void insert_ifnode(ifNode * p);
ifNode* searchif(uint8_t idx, uint8_t mode);
void updateif(uint8_t idx, ifNode * p);

void display();
void displayif();

void ctrlcoverride(int sig) {
    printf("\nCtrl-C - Signal Caught - Exiting\n\n");
    printf(
            "Current Upstream MAC: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x - NHops : %u - At Interface %s\n\n",
            op->upMac[0], op->upMac[1], op->upMac[2], op->upMac[3],
            op->upMac[4], op->upMac[5], op->nHops, op->ifName);
    display();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Node* create(uint64_t sess, uint8_t n[ETH_ALEN], char interface[IF_NAMESIZE]) {
    Node * new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create new node\n");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        strcpy(new->ifName, interface);
        new->session = sess;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
            new->nextHop[i] = n[i];
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }
}

ifNode* createif(uint8_t idx, uint8_t sock, uint8_t ifmac[ETH_ALEN],
        char interface[IF_NAMESIZE]) {
    ifNode * new = (ifNode *) malloc(sizeof(ifNode));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create new interface node\n");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        new->ifIndex = idx;
        new->sock = sock;
        strcpy(new->ifName, interface);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
            new->mac[i] = ifmac[i];
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }
}

void insert_node(Node * p) {
    if (first == last && last == NULL) {
        first = last = p;
        first->next = NULL;
        last->next = NULL;
    } else {
        last->next = p;
        last = last->next;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
}

void insert_ifnode(ifNode * p) {
    if (iffirst == iflast && iflast == NULL) {
        iffirst = iflast = p;
        iffirst->next = NULL;
        iflast->next = NULL;
    } else {
        iflast->next = p;
        iflast = iflast->next;
        iflast->next = NULL;
    }
}

Node* search(uint64_t session) {
    if (first == last && last == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        Node * temp;
        for (temp = first; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->session == session) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

ifNode* searchif(uint8_t idx, uint8_t mode) {
    if (iffirst == iflast && iflast == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        ifNode * temp;
        for (temp = iffirst; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->ifIndex == idx && mode == 0) {
                return temp;
            } else if (temp->sock == idx && mode == 1) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

void update(uint64_t session, Node * p) {
    if (first == last && last == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        Node * temp;
        for (temp = first; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->session == session) {
                strcpy(temp->ifName, p->ifName);
                temp->next = p->next;
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
                    temp->nextHop[i] = p->nextHop[i];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void updateif(uint8_t idx, ifNode * p) {
    if (iffirst == iflast && iflast == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        ifNode * temp;
        for (temp = iffirst; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
            if (temp->ifIndex == idx) {
                strcpy(temp->ifName, p->ifName);
                temp->sock = p->sock;
                temp->next = p->next;
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
                    temp->mac[i] = p->mac[i];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void display() {
    Node * temp = first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Session %" PRIu64 " Through %s - NextHop at ", temp->session,
                temp->ifName);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
            printf("%02x ", temp->nextHop[i]);
        printf("\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void displayif() {
    ifNode * temp = iffirst;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Interface Index %u Socket Number %u - Name %s with MAC: ",
                temp->ifIndex, temp->sock, temp->ifName);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
            printf("%02x ", temp->mac[i]);
        printf("\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

uint8_t counter() {
    Node * temp = first;
    uint8_t counter = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        counter++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return counter;
}

fd_set rfds;
int rec;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, ctrlcoverride);

    cargc = argc;
    cargv = argv;

    /*Setting Base Variables to Initial Values*/
    op = (Stat*) malloc(sizeof(Stat));
    op->nSession = 0;

    memset(op->ifName, 0, IF_NAMESIZE);
    op->maxSocket = 0;
    op->nHops = UINT8_MAX - 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++) {
        op->upMac[i] = 0x00;
    }

    memset(&rfds, 0, sizeof(fd_set));
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("USAGE: sudo %s {provider|node|nodekey}\n", cargv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (!(strcmp(cargv[1], "provider") == 0
            || strcmp(cargv[1], "node") == 0 || strcmp(cargv[1], "nodekey") == 0)) {
        printf("USAGE: sudo %s {provider|node|nodekey}\n", cargv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (strcmp(cargv[1], "nodekey") == 0) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        uint8_t myArray[6] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        insert_node(
                create((uint64_t) (100 * ((float) rand() / RAND_MAX)), myArray,
                        "SOURCE"));
    }

    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (ifa = ifaddr, op->nInterfaces = 0; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;
        if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET
                && strncmp(ifa->ifa_name, "lo", strlen("lo")) != 0
                && strncmp(ifa->ifa_name, "tap", strlen("tap")) != 0) {
            op->nInterfaces++;
        }
    }

    rec = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM));

    int sockopt;
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
    struct ifreq ifr;
    for (i = 1, ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL;

    ifa = ifa->ifa_next, i++) {

        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;
        if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET
                && strncmp(ifa->ifa_name, "lo", strlen("lo")) != 0
                && strncmp(ifa->ifa_name, "tap", strlen("tap")) != 0) {

            uint8_t sock;
            if ((sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM)))
                    == -1) {
                printf("socket() error: %u - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sockopt,
                    sizeof sockopt) == -1) {
                printf("SO_REUSEADDR error: %u - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                close(sock);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
            ifr.ifr_ifindex = i;

            strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifa->ifa_name);

            if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ifa->ifa_name,
            IF_NAMESIZE) == -1) {
                printf("SO_BINDTODEVICE error: %u - %s\n", errno,
                        strerror(errno));
                close(sock);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;

            }

            struct sockaddr_ll sll;
            sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
            sll.sll_ifindex = i;
            sll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM);
            if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, sizeof(sll))) == -1) {
                perror("Error binding raw socket to interface\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

            if ((ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr)) != 0) {
                printf("SIOCGIFHWADDR error: %u - %s\n", errno,
                        strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            int j;

            uint8_t ifmac[ETH_ALEN];
            for (j = 0; j < ETH_ALEN; j++) {
                ifmac[j] = (uint8_t) (ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[j];
            }

            FD_SET(sock, &rfds);

            op->maxSocket = (op->maxSocket < sock) ? sock : op->maxSocket;

            insert_ifnode(createif(i, sock, ifmac, ifr.ifr_name));
        }
    }

    displayif();

    if (strcmp(cargv[1], "provider") == 0) {

        struct ifreq if_mac; // interface

        char * interface = "eth1";

        int sockfd;

        if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM))) == -1) {
            printf("socket() error: %u - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, interface, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
        if ((ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac)) != 0) {
            printf("SIOCGIFHWADDR error: %u - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
            op->upMac[i] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[i];

        op->nHops = 0;

        close(sockfd);
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);

    int stat = 0;

    while (1) {

        if (strcmp(cargv[1], "provider") == 0) {

            if ((stat = receiveP()) != 0)
                return stat;

            if ((stat = broadServ()) != 0)
                return stat;

            display();

            usleep(100000);
        } else if (strcmp(cargv[1], "node") == 0
                || strcmp(cargv[1], "nodekey") == 0) {

            if ((stat = receiveP()) != 0)
                return stat;

            if ((stat = announceSelf()) != 0){
                return stat;
            }

            if ((stat = broadServ()) != 0)
                return stat;

            display();

            usleep(100000);
        }

    }

    ifNode * temp = iffirst;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        close(temp->sock);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    exit(stat);

}

int receiveP() {
    int stat = 0;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    struct sockaddr saddr;

    long unsigned int numbytes = 0;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) buf;

    unsigned int saddr_size = sizeof saddr;

    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = 3; /* 3 Secs Timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;


    setsockopt(rec, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &tv,
            sizeof(struct timeval));

    numbytes = recvfrom(rec, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, &saddr, &saddr_size);

    int len;
    int ntable;

    switch (buf[sizeof(struct ether_header)]) {
    case 1:
        if (buf[sizeof(struct ether_header) + 1] < op->nHops) {
            op->upMac[0] = eh->ether_shost[0];
            op->upMac[1] = eh->ether_shost[1];
            op->upMac[2] = eh->ether_shost[2];
            op->upMac[3] = eh->ether_shost[3];
            op->upMac[4] = eh->ether_shost[4];
            op->upMac[5] = eh->ether_shost[5];

            op->nHops = buf[sizeof(struct ether_header) + 1] + 1;

            memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
            memset(&ifr.ifr_name, 0, IF_NAMESIZE);

            printf(
                    "Server %u Hops Away - Through %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x At Interface %s\n",
                    op->nHops, eh->ether_shost[0], eh->ether_shost[1],
                    eh->ether_shost[2], eh->ether_shost[3], eh->ether_shost[4],
                    eh->ether_shost[5], op->ifName);

            printf("\n\n");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        len = sizeof(struct ether_header) + 1;
        ntable = buf[len++];
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < ntable; j++, len++) {
            if (search(buf[len]) == NULL) {
                insert_node(create(buf[len], eh->ether_shost, ""));
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    return stat;
}

int broadServ() {
    int stat = 0;

    int tx_len = 0;
    char sendbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE - 1];
    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    int i;
    struct ifreq ifr, if_mac;
    ifNode * temp = iffirst;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        /* Get the index of the interface to send on */
        memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        ifr.ifr_ifindex = temp->ifIndex;
        if (ioctl(temp->sock, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr) < 0)
            perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        memset(ifName, 0, IF_NAMESIZE - 1);
        strncpy(ifName, ifr.ifr_name, IF_NAMESIZE - 1);
        /* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on */
        memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
        if (ioctl(temp->sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
            perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");
        if (((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5] == 0x00)
            continue;
        memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
        /* Ethernet header */
        eh->ether_shost[0] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0];
        eh->ether_shost[1] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1];
        eh->ether_shost[2] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2];
        eh->ether_shost[3] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3];
        eh->ether_shost[4] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4];
        eh->ether_shost[5] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5];
        eh->ether_dhost[0] = 0xff;
        eh->ether_dhost[1] = 0xff;
        eh->ether_dhost[2] = 0xff;
        eh->ether_dhost[3] = 0xff;
        eh->ether_dhost[4] = 0xff;
        eh->ether_dhost[5] = 0xff;
        /* Ethertype field */
        eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM);
        tx_len = sizeof(struct ether_header);

        /* Packet data */
        sendbuf[tx_len++] = 1;
        sendbuf[tx_len++] = op->nHops;      //+1;

        /* Index of the network device */
        socket_address.sll_ifindex = temp->ifIndex;
        /* Address length*/
        socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
        /* Destination MAC */
        socket_address.sll_addr[0] = 0xff;
        socket_address.sll_addr[1] = 0xff;
        socket_address.sll_addr[2] = 0xff;
        socket_address.sll_addr[3] = 0xff;
        socket_address.sll_addr[4] = 0xff;
        socket_address.sll_addr[5] = 0xff;

        /* Send packet */
        if (sendto(temp->sock, sendbuf, tx_len, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))
                < 0)
            printf("Send failed\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return stat;
}

int announceSelf() {

    if (op->upMac[0] == 0x00 && op->upMac[1] == 0x00 && op->upMac[2] == 0x00
            && op->upMac[3] == 0x00 && op->upMac[4] == 0x00
            && op->upMac[5] == 0x00)
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    int stat = 0;

    int tx_len = 0;
    char sendbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE - 1];
    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    int i;
    struct ifreq ifr, if_mac;
    ifNode * temp = iffirst;
    while (temp != NULL) {

        memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        ifr.ifr_ifindex = temp->ifIndex;
        if (ioctl(temp->sock, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr) < 0)
            perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        memset(ifName, 0, IF_NAMESIZE - 1);
        strncpy(ifName, ifr.ifr_name, IF_NAMESIZE - 1);
        /* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on */
        memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ - 1);
        if (ioctl(temp->sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
            perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");
        if (((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4] == 0x00
                && ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5] == 0x00)
            continue;
        memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

        /* Ethernet header */
        eh->ether_shost[0] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0];
        eh->ether_shost[1] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1];
        eh->ether_shost[2] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2];
        eh->ether_shost[3] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3];
        eh->ether_shost[4] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4];
        eh->ether_shost[5] = ((uint8_t *) &if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5];
        eh->ether_dhost[0] = op->upMac[0];
        eh->ether_dhost[1] = op->upMac[1];
        eh->ether_dhost[2] = op->upMac[2];
        eh->ether_dhost[3] = op->upMac[3];
        eh->ether_dhost[4] = op->upMac[4];
        eh->ether_dhost[5] = op->upMac[5];
        /* Ethertype field */
        eh->ether_type = htons(ETH_P_CUSTOM);
        tx_len = sizeof(struct ether_header);

        /* Packet data */
        sendbuf[tx_len++] = 2;
        sendbuf[tx_len++] = counter();



        Node *temp1 = first;
        for (; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next) {
            sendbuf[tx_len++] = temp1->session;
        }

        socket_address.sll_ifindex = temp->ifIndex;
        /* Address length*/
        socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
        /* Destination MAC */
        socket_address.sll_addr[0] = op->upMac[0];
        socket_address.sll_addr[1] = op->upMac[1];
        socket_address.sll_addr[2] = op->upMac[2];
        socket_address.sll_addr[3] = op->upMac[3];
        socket_address.sll_addr[4] = op->upMac[4];
        socket_address.sll_addr[5] = op->upMac[5];

        /* Send packet */
        if (sendto(temp->sock, sendbuf, tx_len, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))
                < 0)
            printf("Send failed\n");

        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return stat;
}
```

So to test this you can have VM with linux connected like this (for example):
Provider ----- Node ----- Node ----- Nodekey

I still had a problem when creating multiple sessions, i wasn't incrementing the buffer when reading and I was reading multiple times the same position. Now it's working good

Comment: Sorry but where is the loop that assures that your code comes back to your select? If there is no loop it makes sense that you will get the first frame but not the second.

Comment: oh... I didn't post the whole code... the loop in in the main function...
EDIT: Already posted it... node and nodekey are the same except that nodekey has a element in the structure... node is supposed to propagate the structure through the network till it gets to the provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's begin with the easiest recommendations but I'm not sure this is going to resolve the problem at once. I did a system like this many years ago for different boards with different processor architectures communicating with each other. All the boards were running within a telecommunication switch. It's a very nice problem and you are facing it in the proper way with a peer-to-peer distributed solution.

I didn't go through all code but it seems each node is discovering the neighbour nodes in the network and everyone is creating a tree.

1. In select, the first argument should not be FD_SETSIZE but the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets (in this case the read set), plus 1.
2. The infinite loop is calling receiveSession which is creating all sockets again and then it reads. If a frame with your specific layer-2 protocol arrives in the middle and there is no socket listening for it, it will be discarded. Maybe your problem could be here.
3. When you send Ethernet frames directly, the hardware will complete the frame to the minimum Ethernet size: 64 octets (so you might receive padding data up to 46 octets - Octets not Bytes)
   Please read here:

   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame
4. It is good you chose an EtherType ETH_P_CUSTOM higher than 1536 that is not already in use but maybe you want to use a much higher number in order to minimize possibilities of collision with other protocols.
5. Something important. Your testbed now is with VM's which are usually x86 architectures, 64 bits. When you run your software in real devices with different processors, that might not be the situation. This is very important because you might have different architectures with different endianship and different integer size. That will affect the integer numbers you send, especially in ether_header, and the size of your structures. You have to use the the macros ntohs, ntohl, htons, htonl to change between host and network endianship (session is uint64_t). You should send data in network endianship. This is not solving your very current problem but you might have this problem in the future.

Comment: This is exactly it... It's creating a tree from the provider to the end nodes and then the nodes will initialize sessions which are supposed to be known at the provider.
I will try everything you said here... this sounds like solid good advice. Not sure if this is it but will certainly update

Comment: Something additional: did you check with tcpdump the 2nd frame arrives at the destination node (the one listening)?

Comment: yes... the 2nd frame arrives with the correct structure and in the correct interface... the only thing is that the program can't listem to it... which is kind of weird because I don't think it is a timing problem because it can listen to all the other packets

Comment: Please try to do the changes in (1) and (2) and let's see. Implement the infinite loop around the select and do not close and create sockets all the time.

Comment: Okay I updated the whole think but today I was thinking that maybe I don't need to differentiate the incoming interface because when I send the upstream packet it's a unicast so if it goes the wrong direction the interfaces will just discard it because it's not their IEEE address... I will try to rewrite the code without messing with this whole interface binding stuff (I think maybe it's not binding correctly) and will update soon... probably yet today

Comment: Okay just removed the stuff about the interfaces (most of it)....
It works perfectly now xD